# What exactly gets wiped when unlocking Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, backup, bootloader-lock

I've seen a few guides on how to unlock the Galaxy Nexus to prepare it for rooting, and they say that the `fastboot oem unlock` command will "wipe your personal data".

I'm a little unclear on what gets wiped during this step. Is it just the `/sdcard` area? is it everything but `/system`? Something in between?

I know that `adb backup` can (at least theoretically) back up everything except `/system` while unrooted (see a recent question of mine). But I wonder if I would need to do an `adb restore` of *everything* after the unlock step in order to keep all of my data and settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `/data` and `/sdcard` are erased when you do `fastboot oem unlock`.  So you lose not just files on the "SD card", but all installed applications and their internal settings and data.

Yes, you can use `adb backup` to backup your data and then restore it later, either with `adb restore` or [Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro).  However, when I did this (using `adb restore`), my MMS messages were lost; it seems that the backup didn't save them, though maybe I just did something wrong.

There's also a way to [root without unlocking your bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1894717).  Once rooted, you can use [BootUnlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.segv11.bootunlocker) to unlock it without wiping data.

Comment: That's really good to know! I thought there was only a "root without unlocking" method that worked with 4.0.2. Maybe I will try this.. I don't care about unlocking the bootloader or installing custom recoveries/roms at the moment.